# Using links in json payloads

Tags: ember-data, payload

I found here http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/links-as-property-instead-of-returned-in-json-payload/3271 and in the push docs http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push

that you can send url resources back from the server in a links object

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Bob",
    "links": {
        "friends": "/users/2/friends"
    }
}
```

I would like to do this but can't find this format anywhere else in the docs or jsonapi.org.

In the jsonapi.org docs is says that resource urls can be supported by prepending links before the linked resource http://jsonapi.org/format/#urls-relationships which does not conform with the format above.

Is this format still supported? I actually just want my `hasMany` relationships to be like this whereby regular `belongsTo` relationships are as normal.  Is this possible?

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Bob",
    "address" "5",  //belongsTo
    "links": {
        "friends": "/users/2/friends"   //hasMany
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told that it is OK to mix links with other formats and https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1371 is the official docs for this feature at this time.